# How to combine two methods with different return type but same body with throw statement?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have two methods with different data types, but with same body. I'm not using any `return`. I'm using these methods for throwing exceptions only. Is there any way to combine these two methods or any way to optimize the code?

```
public MyDataType1 method1(MyArg arg){
    /* some logic */
    throw new CustomException();
}
public MyDataType2 method2(MyArg arg){
    /* some logic, same as above method logic*/
    throw new CustomException();
}
```

PS: I don't want to use interface or some new method with common logic.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface to make compatible

```
interface DataType{
}

class MyDataType1 implements DataType{
}

class MyDataType2 implements DataType{
}
```

You'll be able to

```
public DataType method1(MyArg arg){
    /* some logic */
    throw new CustomException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little-known language feature called a 'method' :)

```
public MyDataType1 method1(MyArg arg){
    logic();
    throw new CustomException();
}

public MyDataType2 method2(MyArg arg){
    logic();
    throw new CustomException();
}

private void logic() {
    /* some logic */
}
```